# How to populate a spinner based on radio button selection?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android programming. I have 3 radio buttons (Car,Bike,CV) in a radio group and one spinner. I want to populate the spinner based on the radio button selection. If radio is "Car" clicked, the spinner values must be "item 1, item 2,item 3" and for "bike", the spinner values must be "item 4, item 5, item 6". I tried to implement the concept but desired output is not acheived.

please help

My coding

```
private RadioGroup rg;
private Spinner sp;
int pos;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_vehicle_info);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.VehicleType);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.makeSpinnerCar);

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        pos=rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));

            switch (pos)
            {
            case 0 :
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    sp.setAdapter(adp);
                break;
            case 1 :
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Item 4");
    list.add("Item 5");
    list.add("Item 6");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    sp.setAdapter(adp);
                break;
            case 2 :
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Item 7");
    list.add("Item 8");
    list.add("Item 9");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    sp.setAdapter(adp);
                break;

    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
```

to :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
```

The reason is that `this` here is referring to `OnCheckedChangeListener()` not to the application Context.

Also create List and ArrayAdapter for every case with different names or just use the one you created in case 1, like that:

```
 list = new ArrayList<String>();
adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
```

I tested it and it works

Comment: Thanks karim. With getApplicationContext() the spinner did get populated but the items were not displayed properly. The spinner when clicked, was empty. I achieved the desired result by changing getApplicationContext() to getBaseContext()

Comment: it worked with my with getApplicationContext() but anyway i'm glad that you sort it out :)